# How do you detect time since user has touched mouse or keyboard?

Tags: python3

I'm writing a custom lockscreen/screensaver. I need to determine how long it's been since the user has touched the mouse or keyboard in Python.

Comment: Lookup  `xprintidle` for a command which does this.